# How to write mutation query for inter linked table in GraphQL in React js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am writing mutation query for member enrollment for activity.

```
mutation{
  
  createActivityEnrollments(data:{member:"member1",activity:"Activity 1"}){
    id,
    activity,
    member{
      name
    }
  }
  
}
```

but it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mutation {
  createActivityEnrollment(
    data: { activity: { connect: { id: "DDDD" } } member:{connect:{id:"DDDDDD"}}}
  ){
    member{
      name
    }
    id,
    activity{
      name
    }
  }
```